# openmp distribute threads to certain code blocks

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

In my program I need to divide n threads in following way:

1) Thread1 is doing his specific work

2) n-1 other threads do their own work

If number_of _threads == 1 then only action 1) is done.

Actions 1) and 2) are computed in parallel

```
void main(){
    int number_of_threads;
    std::cin>>number_of_threads;
    omp_set_num_threads(number_of_threads);

    #pragma omp parallel if (number_of_threads>1)
    {
        #pragma omp master // no barrier at the end of master block
            single_calc();

        #pragma omp ??(number_of_threads-1) //second block
            // this section of code is computed by n-1 processes

    }
}
```

I came up to following solutions

1)hardcode so that thread with id == 1 doesn't compute the second block

2)as far as master thread has id = 0 I can use `#pragma omp for` starting with i=1 in the second block

3) call single_calc() outside `#pragma omp parallel` (but I want to control amount of threads calculating this block)

Is there any elegant solution to this?

Comment: What do you mean by elegant, your ideas will probably work, what is it you really want to know? Are you limited to OpenMP or can you use `<thread>` as well?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not do them sequentially? Thread1 can be used in the second part to speed it up with one extra thread.